# Php script not loading (sockets and infinite while)

Tags: php, sockets

I want to create a php script to read and send sockets to a game server but when i load up the script via the browser it just loads and doesnt do anything (infinite loading)

```
    <?php
// Time limit and flushing setting 
set_time_limit(0); 
ob_implicit_flush(); 

// Create the socket and make it listen for 127.0.0.1 on port 7778. 
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, getprotobyname('tcp')) or die("Error in socket_create: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($socket)) . "\n"); 
socket_bind($socket, "127.0.0.1", 7775) or die("Error in socket_bind: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($socket)) . "\n"); 
socket_listen($socket, 5) or die("Error in socket_listen: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($socket)) . "\n"); 

while(true) 
{ 
    // Accept an incoming connection! 
    $spawn = socket_accept($socket); 

    // Send a welcoming notice 
    $welcome = "Hello"; 
    socket_write($spawn, $welcome, strlen($welcome)); 

    while(true) 
    { 
        // Try to read the input 
        $input = socket_read($spawn, 1024, PHP_NORMAL_READ); 
        if($input === false) 
        { 
            // Return to the first loop and look for a new connection to accept. 
            break; 
        } 

        if($input == "Hi, server!") 
        { 
            $response = "Hello to you as well, dear Sir!"; 
            socket_write($spawn, $response, strlen($response)); 
        } 
    } 
} 
socket_close($socket);
?>
```

Comment: When you copy paste code from various sites, do read how to run it and how to use it. These types of scripts aren't ran via browser. And what did you think what does `while(true)` do? Yield visible results? Not a single line of code in that script outputs a single thing.

Comment: I don't want to output anything, just to send a socket back to the server everytime the server sends it to this script

Comment: Do you understand what the script does at all?